# Question about someone who tries to shift attention

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is it called when someone always tries to shift the attention to someone else when theyre being told they are doing something incorrect? For example: A manager is telling an employee that they are taking to long with a project and that employees response is always "well what about so and so? What are they doing?"

Comment: There are multiple aspects of this. One is 'shifting blame'. Another is the recently popular 'whataboutism' (appeal to hypocrisy/pot calling kettle black).

Answer (score 1):

- > A manager is telling an employee that they are taking to long with a
  >   project and the employees response is the usual **deflection**: "well 
  >   what about so and so?

**deflection**.  [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/deflect)

> [transitive] to direct criticism, attention, or blame away from
>   yourself towards someone else

In [Psychology, **deflection**](https://www.learning-mind.com/psychological-deflection/) is seen as a narcissistic abuse tactic used to control the mind and emotions of others.